# Sync files but not folders, windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, sync

I want to sync two files in two different folders on one Windows 7 machine. The problem is there are others files in the same two folders that I do not want to sync. I have searched that there are so many folder sync software, but all of those only support folder sync, not file sync.

Is there any software to sync only files, but not folders?

I am trying to maintain two sets of codes in two different projects, some part of the code has to be the same and have to be kept separately. I hate to edit twice every time there is a change.

I will be really glad if anyone could help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use [FreeFileSync](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freefilesync/) (Free and Open Source). Though it is not meant to sync specifically only files, I usually set `include/exclude` filters to selectively copy only what files I want. You can either specify a pattern or paste filenames in the `include` list. There is a big funnel-shaped red button at the top-center of the window to set those filters